# XML parser incorrectly missing tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am parsing docs from the SEC EDGAR system.
When I use the `lxml` parser, it seems to parse correctly (although it lower-cases XML tags). When I use the `xml` parser, it seems to incorrectly understand the XML.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Example of this behavior on the `<SEC-HEADER>` tag below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = '''<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001193125-20-022930.txt : 20200203
<SEC-HEADER>0001193125-20-022930.hdr.sgml : 20200203
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20200203161106
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001193125-20-022930
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  8-K
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      3
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20200130
ITEM INFORMATION:       Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement
ITEM INFORMATION:       Financial Statements and Exhibits
FILED AS OF DATE:       20200203
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20200203
</SEC-HEADER>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>8-K
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>d879007d8k.htm
<DESCRIPTION>FORM 8-K
<TEXT>
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Form 8-K</TITLE>
</HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">


<Center><DIV STYLE="width:8.5in" align="left">
 <P STYLE="line-height:1.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;border-bottom:1px solid #000000">&nbsp;</P>
<P STYLE="line-height:3.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1px solid #000000">&nbsp;</P> <P STYLE="margin-top:4pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:18pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>UNITED STATES </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:18pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:12pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Washington, D.C. 20549 </B></P> <P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><center>
<P STYLE="line-height:6.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000;width:21%">&nbsp;</P></center> <P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:18pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>FORM <FONT
STYLE="white-space:nowrap">8-K</FONT> </B></P> <P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><center>
<P STYLE="line-height:6.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000;width:21%">&nbsp;</P></center> <P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:12pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>CURRENT REPORT
</B></P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:12pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Pursuant to Section&nbsp;13 or 15(d) </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:12pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934 </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:12pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Date of Report (Date of earliest event reported): January&nbsp;30, 2020 </B></P>
<P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><center> <P STYLE="line-height:6.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000;width:21%">&nbsp;</P></center>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:24pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>MEDALLION FINANCIAL CORP. </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>(Exact name of registrant as specified in its charter) </B></P> <P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><center>
<P STYLE="line-height:6.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000;width:21%">&nbsp;</P></center> <P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Delaware
</B></P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>(State or other jurisdiction of incorporation) </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B><FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">001-37747</FONT> </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>(Commission File Number) </B></P> <P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B><FONT
STYLE="white-space:nowrap">04-3291176</FONT> </B></P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>(IRS Employer Identification No.) </B></P>
<P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><center> <P STYLE="line-height:6.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000;width:21%">&nbsp;</P></center>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>437 Madison Avenue </B></P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>New
York, New York 10022 </B></P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>(Address of principal executive offices) (Zip code) </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B><FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">(212)&nbsp;328-2100</FONT> </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>(Registrant&#146;s telephone number, including area code) </B></P>
<P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><center> <P STYLE="line-height:6.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000;width:21%">&nbsp;</P></center>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">Check the appropriate box below if the Form <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">8-K</FONT> filing is intended to simultaneously satisfy the filing obligation of
the registrant under any of the following provisions: </P> <P STYLE="font-size:6pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
<TR style = "page-break-inside:avoid">
<TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left">&#9744;</TD>
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman; " ALIGN="left">Written communications pursuant to Rule 425 under the Securities Act (17 CFR 230.425) </P></TD></TR></TABLE>
<P STYLE="font-size:6pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
<TR style = "page-break-inside:avoid">
<TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left">&#9744;</TD>
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman; " ALIGN="left">Soliciting material pursuant to Rule <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">14a-12</FONT> under the Exchange Act (17
CFR <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">240.14a-12)</FONT> </P></TD></TR></TABLE> <P STYLE="font-size:6pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
<TR style = "page-break-inside:avoid">
<TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left">&#9744;</TD>
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman; " ALIGN="left"><FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">Pre-commencement</FONT> communications pursuant to Rule <FONT
STYLE="white-space:nowrap">14d-2(b)</FONT> under the Exchange Act (17 CFR <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">240.14d-2(b))</FONT> </P></TD></TR></TABLE> <P STYLE="font-size:6pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
<TR style = "page-break-inside:avoid">
<TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left">&#9744;</TD>
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman; " ALIGN="left"><FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">Pre-commencement</FONT> communications pursuant to Rule <FONT
STYLE="white-space:nowrap">13e-4(c)</FONT> under the Exchange Act (17 CFR <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">240.13e-4(c))</FONT> </P></TD></TR></TABLE>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">Securities registered pursuant to Section&nbsp;12(b) of the Act: </P> <P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" ALIGN="center">


<TR>

<TD WIDTH="34%"></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="32%"></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom" WIDTH="1%"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="32%"></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:8pt">
<TD VALIGN="bottom" NOWRAP ALIGN="center" STYLE="border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Title of each class</B></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="center" STYLE="border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Trading</B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Symbol(s)</B></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="center" STYLE="border-bottom:1.00pt solid #000000"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Name of each exchange</B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; font-size:8pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>on which registered</B></P></TD></TR>


<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="center"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>Common&nbsp;Stock,&nbsp;par&nbsp;value&nbsp;$0.01&nbsp;per&nbsp;share</B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>9.000% Senior Notes due 2021</B></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="center"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>MFIN</B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>MFINL</B></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="center"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>NASDAQ Global Select Market</B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>NASDAQ Global Select Market</B></P></TD></TR>
</TABLE> <P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">Indicate by check mark whether the registrant is an emerging growth company as defined in Rule 405 of the Securities Act of
1933 (&#167;230.405 of this chapter) or <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">Rule&nbsp;12b-2</FONT> of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934 <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">(&#167;240.12b-2</FONT> of this chapter). </P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">Emerging growth company&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9744; </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:8pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">If an
emerging growth company, indicate by check mark if the registrant has elected not to use the extended transition period for complying with any new or revised financial accounting standards provided pursuant to Section&nbsp;13(a) of the Exchange
Act.&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9744; </P> <P STYLE="font-size:8pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P> <P STYLE="line-height:1.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;border-bottom:1px solid #000000">&nbsp;</P>
<P STYLE="line-height:3.0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:2pt;border-bottom:1px solid #000000">&nbsp;</P>
</DIV></Center>


<p Style='page-break-before:always'>
<HR SIZE="3" style="COLOR:#999999" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">


<Center><DIV STYLE="width:8.5in" align="left">

<TABLE STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
<TR style = "page-break-inside:avoid">
<TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left"><B>Item&nbsp;1.01</B></TD>
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman; " ALIGN="left"><B>Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement. </B></P></TD></TR></TABLE>
<P STYLE="margin-top:6pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">On January&nbsp;30, 2020, Freshstart Venture Capital Corp. (&#147;Freshstart&#148;), a wholly-owned subsidiary of Medallion Financial Corp.
(the &#147;Company&#148;), entered into amendments (the &#147;Amendments&#148;) which amended (i)&nbsp;the Loan Agreement, effective as of January&nbsp;25, 2017 (the &#147;Loan Agreement&#148;), by and among U.S. Small Business Administration
(&#147;SBA&#148;), Freshstart and the Company and (ii)&nbsp;the Note, effective March&nbsp;1, 2017 (the &#147;Note&#148;), by Freshstart, to SBA. Under the terms of the Amendments, the maturity date was extended to April&nbsp;1, 2020. Freshstart and
SBA entered into the Amendments while additional amendments to the Loan Agreement and Note are being negotiated and finalized. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">The
foregoing description does not purport to be complete and is qualified in its entirety by reference to the full text of the Amendments, copies of which are filed as Exhibit 4.1 and Exhibit 10.1 to this Current Report on Form <FONT
STYLE="white-space:nowrap">8-K,</FONT> which are incorporated herein by reference. </P> <P STYLE="font-size:18pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
<TR style = "page-break-inside:avoid">
<TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left"><B>Item&nbsp;9.01</B></TD>
<TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE=" margin-top:0pt ; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman; " ALIGN="left"><B>Financial Statements and Exhibits </B></P></TD></TR></TABLE>
<P STYLE="margin-top:6pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">(d)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Exhibits </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">The following exhibits are
being filed with this Current Report on Form <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">8-K:</FONT> </P> <P STYLE="font-size:6pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" WIDTH="92%" BORDER="0" STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt" ALIGN="center">


<TR>

<TD></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom" WIDTH="3%"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="94%"></TD></TR>


<TR STYLE="font-size:1pt">
<TD HEIGHT="8"></TD>
<TD HEIGHT="8" COLSPAN="2"></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top" NOWRAP>&nbsp;&nbsp;4.1</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top"><A HREF="d879007dex41.htm">Amendment No.&nbsp;6 to Note, dated and effective as of January&nbsp;30, 2020, by and between U.S. Small Business Administration and Freshstart Venture Capital Corp. </A></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="font-size:1pt">
<TD HEIGHT="8"></TD>
<TD HEIGHT="8" COLSPAN="2"></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top" NOWRAP>10.1</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top"><A HREF="d879007dex101.htm">Amendment No.&nbsp;7 to Loan Agreement, dated and effective as of January&nbsp;30, 2020, by and between U.S. Small Business Administration and Freshstart Venture Capital Corp. </A></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
 <p STYLE="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt ; font-size:8pt">&nbsp;</P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center">- 2 - </P>

</DIV></Center>


<p Style='page-break-before:always'>
<HR SIZE="3" style="COLOR:#999999" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">


<Center><DIV STYLE="width:8.5in" align="left">
 <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center"><B>SIGNATURE </B></P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">Pursuant to the requirements of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934, as amended, the registrant has duly caused this report to be signed on
its behalf by the undersigned hereunto duly authorized. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">Dated: February&nbsp;3, 2020 </P>
<P STYLE="font-size:12pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P><DIV ALIGN="right">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" WIDTH="40%" BORDER="0" STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">


<TR>

<TD WIDTH="7%"></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="14%"></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom" WIDTH="1%"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="77%"></TD></TR>


<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top" COLSPAN="5"><B>MEDALLION FINANCIAL CORP.</B></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="font-size:1pt">
<TD HEIGHT="16"></TD>
<TD HEIGHT="16" COLSPAN="4"></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top">By:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" COLSPAN="3"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; border-bottom:1px solid #000000; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><I>/s/ Larry D. Hall</I></P></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Name:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Larry D. Hall</TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Title:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Chief Financial Officer</TD></TR>
</TABLE></DIV>
 <p STYLE="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt ; font-size:8pt">&nbsp;</P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center">- 3 - </P>

</DIV></Center>

</BODY></HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>EX-4.1
<SEQUENCE>2
<FILENAME>d879007dex41.htm
<DESCRIPTION>EX-4.1
<TEXT>
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>EX-4.1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">

<p Style='page-break-before:always'>
<HR SIZE="3" style="COLOR:#999999" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">


<Center><DIV STYLE="width:8.5in" align="left">
 <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><B>SECTION 5.</B> <U>Counterparts</U>. This Amendment may be executed by each of the parties
hereto on any number of separate counterparts, each of which shall be an original and all of which taken together shall constitute one and the same instrument. Delivery of an executed signature page of this Amendment in Portable Document Format
(PDF) or by facsimile transmission shall be effective as delivery of an executed original counterpart of this Amendment. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><B>SECTION
6.</B> <U>Governing Law</U>.<B> </B>Pursuant to Section&nbsp;101.106(b) of Part 13 of the Code of Federal Regulations, this Amendment is to be construed and enforced in accordance with the Act, the Regulations and other Federal law, and in the
absence of applicable Federal law, then by applicable New York law to the extent it does not conflict with the Act, the Regulations or other Federal law. </P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center">[SIGNATURES APPEAR ON NEXT PAGE] </P>
 <p STYLE="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt ; font-size:8pt">&nbsp;</P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center">2 </P>

</DIV></Center>


<p Style='page-break-before:always'>
<HR SIZE="3" style="COLOR:#999999" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">


<Center><DIV STYLE="width:8.5in" align="left">
 <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">IN WITNESS WHEREOF, the parties have caused this Amendment to be executed by their
respective officers thereunto duly authorized, as of the date first above written. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">FRESHSTART VENTURE CAPITAL CORPORATION </P>
<P STYLE="font-size:12pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">&nbsp;</P>
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" WIDTH="40%" BORDER="0" STYLE="BORDER-COLLAPSE:COLLAPSE; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">


<TR>

<TD WIDTH="10%"></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="16%"></TD>

<TD VALIGN="bottom" WIDTH="1%"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="72%"></TD></TR>


<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top">By:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; border-bottom:1px solid #000000; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">/s/ Thomas J. Munson</P></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Name:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Thomas J. Munson</TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Title:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">SVP</TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="font-size:1pt">
<TD HEIGHT="16"></TD>
<TD HEIGHT="16" COLSPAN="4"></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" COLSPAN="3">U.S.&nbsp;SMALL&nbsp;BUSINESS&nbsp;ADMINISTRATION</TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="font-size:1pt">
<TD HEIGHT="16"></TD>
<TD HEIGHT="16" COLSPAN="2"></TD>
<TD HEIGHT="16" COLSPAN="2"></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="top">By:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:1pt; border-bottom:1px solid #000000; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman">/s/ Thomas G. Morris</P></TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Name:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Thomas G. Morris</TD></TR>
<TR STYLE="page-break-inside:avoid ; font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:10pt">
<TD VALIGN="top"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">Title:</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" NOWRAP>Director, O/L &amp; Acting Deputy A/A OII</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
 <p STYLE="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt ; font-size:8pt">&nbsp;</P> <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center">3 </P>

</DIV></Center>

</BODY></HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>EX-10.1
<SEQUENCE>3
<FILENAME>d879007dex101.htm
<DESCRIPTION>EX-10.1
<TEXT>
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>EX-10.1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">
    
<p Style='page-break-before:always'>
<HR SIZE="3" style="COLOR:#999999" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">


<Center><DIV STYLE="width:8.5in" align="left">
 <P STYLE="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><B>SECTION 4.</B> <U>Limited Effect</U>. Except as expressly amended and modified by this
Amendment, the Existing Agreement shall continue to be, and shall remain, in full force and effect in accordance with its terms (and as duly amended). </P>
<P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><B>SECTION 5.</B> <U>Counterparts</U>. This Amendment may be executed by each of the parties hereto on any number of separate counterparts,
each of which shall be an original and all of which taken together shall constitute one and the same instrument. Delivery of an executed signature page of this Amendment in Portable Document Format (PDF) or by facsimile transmission shall be
effective as delivery of an executed original counterpart of this Amendment. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><B>SECTION 6.</B> <U>Governing Law</U>.<B> </B>Pursuant to
Section&nbsp;101.106(b) of Part 13 of the Code of Federal Regulations, this Amendment is to be construed and enforced in accordance with the Act, the Regulations and other Federal law, and in the absence of applicable Federal law, then by applicable
New York law to the extent it does not conflict with the Act, the Regulations or other Federal law. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman" ALIGN="center">[SIGNATURES APPEAR ON NEXT PAGE] </P>
</DIV></Center>


<p Style='page-break-before:always'>
<HR SIZE="3" style="COLOR:#999999" WIDTH="100%" ALIGN="CENTER">

</BODY></HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
</SEC-DOCUMENT>
'''
BeautifulSoup(markup=doc, features= 'lxml').find_all('sec-header') # the closing tag is correctly found. 
BeautifulSoup(markup=doc, features= 'xml').find_all('SEC-HEADER') # the closing tag is somehow (incorrectly) appended at the very bottom of the entire doc
```

Comment: The reason may be that your XML document isn't wellformed: element `ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME` must be terminated by the matching end-tag.

Comment: The document is not well-formed and therefore it is not XML.

Comment: The document is sgml, not xml (2nd line: `<SEC-HEADER>xxx.hdr.sgml`).

Answer (score 0):

Jack Fleeting answered in the comments above:

> The document is sgml, not xml (2nd line: xxx.hdr.sgml

And consequently, the tags aren’t XML formatted